# Django Rest Framework, how to use serializers.ListField with model and view?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to store an array of integers in the day_of_the_week field. for which I am using the following code

models.py

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    day_of_the_week = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers.py

```
class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    day_of_the_week = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta():
        model = Schedule
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views.py

```
# schedule list
class ScheduleList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        scheduleData = Schedule.objects.all()
        serializer = ScheduleSerializer(scheduleData, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ScheduleSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response("Schedule Added")
```

[image]

Data save successfully but when I try to get data it returns data in this format

```
"day_of_the_week": [
            "[2",
            " 1]"
        ],
```

is there any way to get an array of integers as a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While saving try to add the child field in the serializer:

```
class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    day_of_the_week = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_day_of_the_week(self, instance):

        return instance.day_of_the_week[1:-1].split(',')


    class Meta():
        model = Schedule
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: but this return when get method is called "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[2'" it tries to convert '[2' to integer

Comment: Your input is in the wrong format. Try to send a valid array of numbers like [2, 1]

Comment: no in getting data it takes input from the database where the array is stored in string format = "[1,2]" so when trying to get data it tries to convert [1 to an integer and shows an error.

Comment: can you share the GetScheduleSerializer as well in the above question?

Comment: In GetScheduleSerializer I remove "day_of_the_week = serializers.ListField()" to solve that error but then it returns data in string format

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope it helps.